# How to Resolve a SystemStackError in Ruby on Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## Trying to create category, Getting SystemStackError (stack level too deep) in rails 6

I'm encountering a SystemStackError in my Ruby on Rails application, specifically in one of my controllers. I've been trying to debug it, but I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact cause. Here's the error message and the relevant part of my controller:

**server logs**

```
Started POST "/api/v1/categories" for ::1 at 2023-09-07 00:30:36 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::CategoriesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Electronics", "category"=>{"name"=>"Electronics"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."token" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in `authenticate_request'
  TRANSACTION (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `authenticate_request'
  User Update (1.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "sign_in_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["sign_in_count", 2], ["current_sign_in_at", "2023-09-06 19:00:36.703908"], ["updated_at", "2023-09-06 19:00:36.704756"], ["id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `authenticate_request'
  TRANSACTION (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `authenticate_request'
  TRANSACTION (0.8ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  Category Create (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Electronics"], ["created_at", "2023-09-06 19:00:36.729039"], ["updated_at", "2023-09-06 19:00:36.729039"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Category"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb:18:in `create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 85ms (ActiveRecord: 21.6ms | Allocations: 40064)
 
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  
app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb:18:in `create'

**SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

app/controllers/api/v1/categories_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

And here's the code for the index action in api/v1/categories_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
   
      def index
        @categories = Category.all
        # render json: @categories
      end

      def show
        render json: @category
      end

      def create
        @category = Category.new(category_params)

        if @category.save
          render json: @category, status: :created
        else
          render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

      def update
        if @category.update(category_params)
          render json: @category
        else
          render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @category.destroy
        # head :no_content
      end

      private

      def set_category
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
      end

      def category_params
        params.require(:category).permit(:name, :image)
      end

end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include JsonWebToken
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  before_action :authenticate_request
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  attr_reader :current_user

  private
  
  def authenticate_request
    token = request.headers['Authorization']&.split(' ')&.last
    user = User.find_by(token: token)
    if user.present?
      sign_in user, store: false
    else
      render json: { error: 'Invalid token' }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:mobile_number, :email, :first_name, :last_name]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
  
end
```

I've checked the code, and it doesn't seem to contain any obvious recursive function calls. What could be causing this SystemStackError in this context?

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: The error is occurring on `create`. Do you have any callbacks in your model? Maybe an `after_save` that calls `save`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post your model

Comment: Please reorganise the `before_action`. Place `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?` before `before_action :authenticate_request`.

Comment: model

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
    has_many :subcategories
    has_one_attached :image
end